# has_many with multiple table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, has-many-through

I have a MovieSession has many ticket

```
class MovieSession < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :tickets
end
```

A ticket belongs_to a room and has many bookings

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :bookings
belongs_to :room
end
```

Booking like a join table between Seat and Ticket

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :ticket
belongs_to :seat
end
```

In rails is it possible if I get all booked seat. Like below?

```
class MovieSession < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :seats, through :ticket and booking 
end
```

Comment: These models don't seem to accurately represent your question. Take a moment to check the relationships are all defined on both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all the seats for a movie, you want to go to the seat model and add a scope that joins the appropriate tables. Something like:

```
class Seat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :booking

  scope :by_movie, -> (_movie) { joins(:booking => {:ticket => :movie}).where(movie: _movie) }
```